# Minimizing Mean Square Error

Tags: estimation, unbiased-estimator, mse, exponential-distribution, lagrange-multipliers

Suppose we have a random sample $\textbf{X}=(X_1,...,X_n)$ from a shifted exponential distribution with common density
$f(x|\theta)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
e^{-(x-\theta)} & x\geq \theta\\ 
0 & x<\theta
\end{matrix}\right.$

How does one find the linear estimator of the form $\hat{\theta}=a_0+\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_iX_i$ with the smallest mean square error? Is it right to assume that this estimator is unbiased?

I have calculated $E[X_i]=\theta+1$ and $Var[X_i]=1$. If we are assuming this estimator to be unbiased, then we would have $$MSE[\hat{\theta}]=Var[\hat{\theta}]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^{2}$$

I am trying to compute the MSE so this is the equation I would need to minimize. With the unbiased assumption, then we can say that $$E[\hat{\theta}]=a_0+(\theta+1)\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i=\theta$$

Am I right to use this above equation as the constraint of a Lagrange multiplier problem? Should the constraint be $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i =\frac{\theta-a_0}{\theta+1}$?

Comment: Do you mean an unbiased estimator of $1+\theta$ or of $\theta$? As one is unbiased and the other not. More generally, I do not understand the question since there exists a minimal sufficient statistic in that case and hence a UMVUE.

Comment: An estimator of the location parameter $\theta$ with the smallest mean square error.

Comment: How do I know if that is in the form I have specified? I need the estimator of that form with the smallest MSE.

Comment: This is a `self-study` question, so please add the tag and develop further what you have tried to solve this question.